# Export files to public FileSystem

Tags: codenameone

I need to save some files to a directory the user could open from his folder explorer app. 
I tried using the ShareButton and the share function from Display but it does not allow to save to the fileSystem.

I wanted to use FileChooser to let the user pick a folder in order to get the folder path and save my file in it but I don't think you can select a folder using The FileChooser.

So I thought I could use FileSystemStorage using getRoots and listFiles to let the user find the folder he wants to save the file to. But I noticed that getRoots does not return the sdCard path of my Android 8 device.

And even if the FileSystemStorage returns the sdcard path corectly, it does not make sense on IOS since there is no public folder is IOS ? Or can we export a file to a document directory ? I also don't know what would return getRoots on IOS since I don't have an iphone.

I am starting to think that to export a file I will have to do it natively. Am I correct or have I missed something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS doesn't really have something like an SD card or a shared directory. You can do that in Android using a bit of manifest wiggling in Codename One but I don't have any experience with it. Frankly it's a bit of a gray zone since things behave differently between Android versions and I just wouldn't go there.

Share should allow you to send a file to any other app similar to the way intents work on Anroid. It should work with iOS too and is the best way to share a single file. You can also use email to send an attachment if you are looking for that specific case.

The trick with share is to pass it a file system path within the app home directory. Once you do that our native implementation transfers it to the appropriate API's that make it accessible to other apps.

Comment: Alright, I'll  use the share API and I'll also let the user save the file in a directory using getExternalStorageDirectory if it is available. Thanks